# Understanding a lighttpd.conf file?

Tags: html, webserver, lighttpd

I've been given a lighttpd.conf that someone else wrote and need help working out how to serve it. I'm 90% of the way there but stuck... The index.html page appears, but links and CSS files don't point to the right place.

To clarify, the links and CSS files are all pointing to a 'file:///' URL. So `styles.css` in the HTML header points to `file:///html/styles.css`, whereas it should be going to `http://example.com/styles.css`

Maybe url.rewrite or url.redirect isn't working properly?

```
server.document-root = "~/html"
server.port = 28001
mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png" 
)
url.rewrite = (
  "^(.*)/($|\?.*)" => "$1/index.html",
  "^(.*)/([^.?]+)($|\?.*)$" => "$1/$2.html"
)
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  url.redirect = ( 
                   "^/platform/index.html$" => "/platform",
                   "^/about/company.html$" => "/about/company",,
  )
}
```

----- UPDATE ------

`file:///` problem now solved, thanks to Marcel. However, http://example.com/about/company still doesn't find anything, whereas http://example.com/about/company.html renders OK. Is there a problem with url.rewrite? I'm using v1.4.20 of lighttpd, so maybe I need to change it to rewrite-once or rewrite-final?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the HTML pages you serve, containing `file://`, not with a configuration option of your web server. Do you have an example page?

Comment: You're right! That problem is now solved - thank you. (If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it so you get the points.) The redirect still isn't working properly though...

Comment: Those two URLs in your update aren't really pointing to something you made, but are there merely as an example? Then use example.com, so everyone can see it's an example (and you don't confuse the people using url.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the original problem: it's not a problem of web server configuration, but of the HTML being served, likely containing the `file://` protocol. Use `http://` instead.

Regarding the second problem: I'm not an expert in Lighttpd configuration options, but it might help if you exchange those settings in `url.redirect` and get rid of the trailing commas, like:

```
  url.redirect = ( 
                   "^/platform$" => "/platform/index.html",
                   "^/about/company$" => "/about/company.html"
  )
```

(but I'm not sure). See [the documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRedirect) for examples.

BTW, is `mod_redirect` loaded in `server.modules`?

Comment: Yep - you're right on both counts - adding 'server.modules = ( "mod_redirect" )' solved the problem. THANK YOU!